# Take random row for GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I need one row for each *textid*. But it has to be chosen random, not the first in the MySQL table.

Shuffling like this does not work. It still takes the first row.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM textelements ORDER BY rand()
) AS z
GROUP BY z.textid;
```

Read the comments for my solution. I added LIMIT 1000000 to the subquery.

Comment: possibly take advantage of `GROUP_CONCAT` with `ORDER BY RAND()` to get a random row_id for each textid

Comment: *Shuffling like this does not work.* ORDER BY applied in the subquery is lost in outer query.

Comment: @Akina is lost unless you put limit inside the subquery.

Comment: @ErgestBasha It provides limiting in the subquery, for the subquery output - but in outer query the ordering will be lost anycase. I have not told that the ordering in the subquery makes no sense...

Comment: @Akina maybe I didn't explain correctly what I meant. The idea is if you do not put limit in order by inside the subquery the order is lost in outer. If you use order by and limit inside the subquery , the order is saved in outer query.  An explanation from MariaDB : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/.

Comment: @ErgestBasha *If you use order by and limit inside the subquery , the order **is saved** in outer query.* This is incorrect. "The order **may be saved** in outer query" is correct. May, but not must.

Comment: @ErgestBasha: I can confirm a limit in the Subquery works and fixes everything. According to the documentation you provided this might be a stable method.

Comment: @netAction every time I used it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( 
    SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY textid ORDER BY RAND()) rn
    FROM textelements 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: @netAction For version 5 you may use the method provided in ProGu's comment to your question.